# Setting the default browser

Tags: macos, web-browsing

Is there any way to set the default web browser from within Mac OS?

I currently run Firefox 4 Beta, and haven't been able to find anywhere within the browser to set it as the default - possibly because it *is* a Beta. However, this makes Chrome start up as soon as I click a link from somewhere other than within FF, which is a tad annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open Safari
2. <kbd>⌘,</kbd> to open Preferences
3. On the General tab there's a pull down that says 'Default web browser', the the one you want from the list

Comment: To think that it would be in another web browser! First slightly illogical preference I've seen from Apple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "[Default Apps](http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/set-default-applications-in-mac-os-x/)" for change every default application.

[image]

Comment: Where is this? Is this a plug-in or extension?

Comment: It's 3rd-party app you can install it and use it in system preferences